# Snapchat video caption removal

Tags: video, snapchat, captions

My friend posted a snap video weeks ago and someone has managed to record it and also remove a caption that was present.

Can anyone explain how this is possible?

Really appreciate any feedback

Comment: With no before/after images to understand what happened no-one can answer you correctly. Was the caption static (like a logo)? Some video editors have "logo removal" option so maybe they used that? It's a yes if looking where logo/text/caption was positioned, is the area now blurry in any subtle way? Caption can also mean subtitle, was the subtitle track simply removed from the MP4? Was the video even MP4 or was webM?

Comment: PS: How is this a **programming** question? Maybe use your account to ask at either **https://superuser.com/** or **https://video.stackexachange.com** since they deal with end-user questions. **Stackoverflow** is for software development related questions...